# SBT project compilation error related to certs

Tags: ssl, playframework, sbt

When I try to build sbt project from IntelliJ or Command prompt, I get error related to SSL handshake.  Simple "Hello World" project compiles but when I cnclude plugin for Play framework, I get these errors.

I added repo.scala-sbt.org, dl.bintray.com certificates to Java Keystore as well as keystore path (Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore) to sbt config,  but it is not resolving the issue. Any suggestion to resolve this issue?

-- TIA

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="\jre\lib\security\cacerts"

[error] (update) lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.error.FetchError$DownloadingArtifacts: Error fetching artifacts:

[error] https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.8.2/jars/sbt-plugin.jar: download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.8.2/jars/sbt-plugin.jar

[error] https:repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.1/jars/sbt-native-packager.jar: download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https:repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.1/jars/sbt-native-packager.jar

[error] https:repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.1/docs/sbt-native-packager-javadoc.jar: download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https:repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.1/docs/sbt-native-packager-javadoc.jar

[error] https:repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/docs/sbt-js-engine-javadoc.jar: download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https:repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/docs/sbt-js-engine-javadoc.jar

[error] https:repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-web/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.4.4/docs/sbt-web-javadoc.jar: download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https:repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-web/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.4.4/docs/sbt-web-javadoc.jar

Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. One of the certs in certificate chain (akamai.bintray.com) was missing in my trust store. After I added this cert, SBT project compilation worked.

repo.scala-sbt.org -> dl.bintray.com -> akamai.bintray.com

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.8.2/jars/sbt-plugin.jar